# Debugging Javascript in Embedded Resource

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

What is the best way to debug JavaScript in visual studio embedded resource JavaScript files?

Since the JavaScript is compiled into a library setting breakpoints on the source file do not work. To break execution and use breakpoints we've been putting a reference to an undefined variable which visual studio detects. Once you hit the undefined variable you can set breakpoints and debug normally.

The problem I am having is that visual studio is no longer detecting the undefined variable.

What is the best way to debug JavaScript in visual studio when you are using an embedded resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used either IE's built in debugger (you will need to detach the IE process from VS), or in Firefox I use FireBug.

The other thing I have used is the debugger keyword in the javascript.

Comment: Chrome as one of the best javascript debugger, built-in.